# javaScript True/False with variable declaration

Tags: javascript, boolean

I'm a bit confused with this. Does `if (clickTimeout)` mean "if clickTimeout is true" or "if clickTimeout is false"(Because there's a var declaration)?

```
var clickTimeout = false;

if (clickTimeout) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: _Because there's a var declaration_ how will that make a difference?

Comment: `if(expression)` checks if `expression` is [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). The variable `clickTimeout` is not truthy. So, it will not enter the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!clickTimeout) {
 return;
}
```

This means "if clickTimeout is false"